# Run two instances of the same react application on the same computer

Tags: reactjs

How would I run two instances of the same react application on the same machine. I have a instant chat app Im building and I want to test it but I have no way to because I dont know how to run the app twice at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open two terminals on the same project root directory and run `npm start` in each terminal. Now each instance will run on a different port number on your machine. Make sure to answer Yes in the second terminal when it asks you if you want to run the application on a different port than the first one.